# How can I include scoped model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

If I just including nested model in query such this

```
@projects = current_user.projects.all(include: :reviews)
```

everything ok. But Review model has some scope, that I need implement in query above. I trying this

```
@projects = current_user.projects.all(include: :reviews.unreaded)
```

and gets error. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create an association based on the scope, roughly:

```
@projects = current_user.projects.all(include: :unread_reviews)
```

Then create an `unread_reviews` association, roughly:

```
class Project < ...
  has_many :unread_reviews, :conditions => ['read=?', true], :class_name => "Review"
```

(Replace the above `has_many` with your association particulars, obviously.)

This technique is discussed in the [association docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Eager+loading+of+associations).